# How to check which desktop GUI environment is installed on my Ubuntu machine

Tags: gui, desktop-environments

I have an AWS Ubuntu machine.

I want to find out which desktop GUI environment is installed and running on my Ubuntu machine.

Every time I'm logging into Ubuntu I'm getting the GNOME environment. I want to uninstall it and install `mate-desktop` instead.

How can I do this?

Comment: Install `mate-desktop`, log out, log back in on the Mate desktop (gear icon on the login screen allows to choose desktop environment). Precisely removing all packages only needed when running the gnome desktop is not trivial, unless someone has compiled a list. `sudo apt-remove ubuntu-desktop` followed by a `sudo apt autoremove` may already remove quite a lot.

Comment: As im loggint this machine using Windows RDP, I am not getting gear icon while logging in.